# Is it possible to titleize in IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

I tried this :

```
User.find(1).update_attribute('first_name', '#{first.name.titleize}')

=> /#{first.name.titleize}
```

I am not sure any other way to do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You need to use double quotes, ruby does not interpolate the embedded variable in single quotes.

Second, you need to bind the user to a variable in order to access the first_name attribute.

This should work:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.update_attribute(:first_name, u.first_name.titleize)
```